# How to create a custom model class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

sorry if this is a simple question or if I'm doing something wrong, but I am fairly new to both keras/tensorflow and python. I am trying to test some different models for image classification based on transfer learning. For that, I wanted to create a function to build a model where I only specified some parameters, and it automatically generates the desired model.
I have written the following code:

```
class modelMaker(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, img_height, img_width, trained='None'):
    super(modelMaker, self).__init__()
    self.x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3),name="input_layer")
    if (trained == 'None'):
      pass
    elif (trained == 'ResNet50'):
      self.x = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(self.x)
      IMG_SHAPE = (img_height,img_width) + (3,)
      base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                                  include_top=False,
                                                  weights='imagenet')
      base_model.trainable = False
      for layer in base_model.layers:
        if isinstance(layer, keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
          layer.trainable = True
        else:
          layer.trainable = False
      self.x = base_model(self.x)

  def call(self, inputs):
    return self.x(inputs)
```

For now I only implemented the ResNet50 and an empty option, but I am planning to add more. The reason I tried to add layers using  `self.x = LAYER(self.x)` was because the model can have a different number of layers based on future parameters.

However, when I try to get the summary of the model, using `model.summary()`, I get the following error:

> ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.

Is it possible to build models like this?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.summary()` needs some information about the input shape and the structure of your model (layers), in order to print them for you. So, somewhere you should give this information to the `model` object.

If you use a **Sequential** model or **Functional API**, just specifying `input_shape` parameter for running `model.summary()` is enough. If you don't specify `input_shape` then you may call your model or use `model.build` to give this information.

But when you are using **subclassing** (Like what you did), objects of this class have no information about shapes and layers, unless you call the `call()` function (since you are defining your layers structure in the `call` function and passing input to it).

There are 3 ways to call `call()` function:

1. `model.fit()`: calls it while training

   - may not fit your need, since you have to first train your model.
2. `model.build()`: calls it internally

   - Just pass the shape of input like `model.build((1,128,128,3))`
3. `model()`: call it directly

   - you need to pass at least one sample (tensor) like `model(tf.random.uniform((1,128,128,3))`

Modified code should be like this:

```
class modelMaker(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, img_height, img_width, num_classes=1, trained='dense'):
        super(modelMaker, self).__init__()
        self.trained = trained
        self.IMG_SHAPE = (img_height,img_width) + (3,)
        # define common layers
        self.flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="flatten")
        self.classify = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, name="classify")
        # define layers for when "trained" != "resnet"
        if self.trained == "dense":
            self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, name="dense128") 
        
        # layers for when "trained" == "resnet"
        else:
            self.pre_resnet = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input
            self.base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_shape=self.IMG_SHAPE, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
            self.base_model.trainable = False
            for layer in self.base_model.layers:
                if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
                    layer.trainable = True
                else:
                    layer.trainable = False
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        # define your model without resnet 
        if self.trained == "dense":
            x = self.flat(inputs)
            x = self.dense(x)
            x = self.classify(x)
            return x
        # define your model with resnet
        else:
            x = self.pre_resnet(inputs)
            x = self.base_model(x)
            x = self.flat(x)
            x = self.classify(x)
            return x
        
    # add this function to get correct output for model summary
    def summary(self):
        x = tf.keras.Input(shape=self.IMG_SHAPE, name="input_layer")
        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))
        return model.summary()
    
model = modelMaker(128, 128, trained="resnet") # create object
model.build((10,128,128,3))                    # build model
model.summary()                                # print summary
```

Output is:

```
Model: "model_9"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_layer (InputLayer)           [(None, 128, 128, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf.__operators__.getitem_6 ( (None, 128, 128, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf.nn.bias_add_6 (TFOpLambda (None, 128, 128, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
resnet50 (Functional)        (None, 4, 4, 2048)        23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 32768)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
classify (Dense)             (None, 1)                 32769     
=================================================================
Total params: 23,620,481
Trainable params: 32,769
Non-trainable params: 23,587,712
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, really appreciate it as a begginer. This changes work well if I keep >training as "None". However, when I tried to change >training to "ResNet50", I get the error >TypeError: 'InputLayer' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @er3016 I didn't check your resnet part code. There are some issues in there. I will update my answer, with resolving those issues.